# Error "'_unsafeSelectionEnd' is defined as a property in class 'HTMLMaskElement'"

Tags: angular

I am taking this error from:

Error:

Error: node_modules/imask/esm/controls/html-input-mask-element.d.ts:11:9 - error TS2611: '_unsafeSelectionEnd' is defined as a property in class 'HTMLMaskElement', but is overridden here in 'HTMLInputMaskElement' as an accessor.

11     get _unsafeSelectionEnd(): number;

Error: node_modules/imask/esm/controls/html-input-mask-element.d.ts:14:9 - error TS2611: 'value' is defined as a property in class 'HTMLMaskElement', but is overridden here in 'HTMLInputMaskElement' as an accessor.

14     get value(): string;

Print Error:
[image]

Component:

[image]

HTML:

[image]

Version:

[image]

How to solve the problem?